# Installing Hive on Windows 8.1 error "Missing Hive Execution Jar: C:\hive\lib/hive-exec-*.jar"

Tags: hive, hadoop2

I am following these [instructions](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/AdminManual+Installation) to install Hive on Windows 8.1

I downloaded Hive tar from [Hive Apache page] (http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi/hive/) and extracted to folder c:\hive\

I have added a new `System Variable` set to `HIVE_HOME = c:\hive`

I have added `c:\hive\bin` to `Path`

I already have `Hadoop 2.7.5` up and running fine.

When I try to run hive at command line I get following error:

```
"Missing Hive Execution Jar: C:\hive\lib/hive-exec-*.jar"
```

Some of the other SO question/answers suggest .jar files are in other folders.

But I can't find any .jar files in the extracted folders.

I don't want to download any .jars as other answers suggest. Shouldn't required .jar file be in the tar file?

I have vague impression that maybe Hadoop has the required .jar files, and there is something I need to do to tell Hive to get those?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so it looks like you do have download a previous version tar file of Hive and extract it to use the .jar files in its /lib folder.

I had originally downloaded apache-hive-2.1.0 and set that up but it didn't have the .jar files in its /lib folder.

So I went to http://apache.mirror.iweb.ca/hive/ and downloaded hive-1.0.1 and which had .jar files in it.

Then copied those in the empty /lib file in apache-hive-2.1.0 installation.

Now Hive is working fine!